# Using autoencoder for pairwise text similarity

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, word2vec, autoencoder

I have a dataset containing only 500 samples. The dataset has three columns

1. Sentence1
2. Sentence2
3. 0 or 1 (to indicate similarity).

My task was to train an encoder that takes two sentences as input and returns 1 if sentences are similar and 0 otherwise.

I use pre-trained word2vec embeddings to extract features. My model has achieved only 50% accuracy.

```
sent_in = Input(shape=(150, ))
sent_emb = Embedding(input_dim=vocab_size, output_dim=300, weights=[E],)(sent_in)
conv1 = Conv1D(32, 5, activation='relu', padding='same')(sent_emb)
pool1 = MaxPooling1D(2)(conv1)
conv2 = Conv1D(64, 5, activation='relu', padding='same')(pool1)
pool2 = MaxPooling1D(2)(conv2)
conv3 = Conv1D(128, 5, activation='relu', padding='same')(pool2)
flat1 = Flatten()(conv3)

sent_in2 = Input(shape=(150, ))
sent_emb2 = Embedding(input_dim=vocab_size, output_dim=300, weights=[E],)(sent_in2)
conv4 = Conv1D(32, 5, activation='relu', padding='same')(sent_emb2)
pool3 = MaxPooling1D(2)(conv4)
conv5 = Conv1D(64, 5, activation='relu', padding='same')(pool3)
pool4 = MaxPooling1D(2)(conv5)
conv6 = Conv1D(128, 5, activation='relu', padding='same')(pool4)
flat2 = Flatten()(conv6)

concatenated = concatenate([flat1, flat2])

dense1 = Dense(32, activation='relu')(concatenated)
out = Dense(1, activation='sigmoid')(dense1)
model = Model(inputs=[sent_in,sent_in2], outputs=out)
model.summary()
```

My network is illustrated in the image below

[image: My Network]

Questions:

1) Must every autoencoder have an encoder and a decoder?

2) How can I improve my accuracy?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ***1) Must every autoencoder have an encoder and a decoder?***

Yes, it's a must. If you are going to train the encoder and decoder as separate neural networks you may soon face the problem that we do not know the ground truth of what the encoding (compressed set of features) ought to be.
There is no label to say that the input features should correspond to this particular encoding.
Thus, it’s impossible to train our encoder! Without the encoder, we will not have the encoding and thus we have no input features to the decoder!
This makes it impossible to train our decoder as well!

> ***2) How can I improve my accuracy?***

Well I think this has been answered here: [How to improve the accuracy of autoencoder?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54643064/how-to-improve-the-accuracy-of-autoencoder)

The following explanation below can also help:

**The effect of an auto-encoder on the accuracy of a convolutional neural network classification task**

It is reasonable to say that a lower encoded size leads to lower accuracy and the accuracy becomes stable when the
encoded size reaches a certain number because ***a lower encoded size means more loss*** in the image data, which means
the restructured image would be more different from the original data. Moreover, even though the encoded size is large
enough, there is still a loss in the image data. Hence, the accuracy is still less than the original accuracy and the accuracy
in the box plot stops increasing. When the ***auto-encoders*** are trained with the encoded size which is large enough, the
accuracy for both cases is about 92%. Compared to CNN which takes original data as input and achieves the
accuracy of 99%, the accuracy loss due to auto-encoders is not too much.

This is based on the research paper.